# want to change the program coded for push button to a normal switchbutton

Tags: button, automation, arduino, feedback, blynk

So basically, i am working on a **Feedback system** for **Home automation** ,which updates the state of the physical button connected to your board onto the **Blynk** app, so that you can control your lights from both - manually and through the app.I am using an **ESP32** board.The state of the physical button connected to the board is taken and is sent to the virtual button on the blynk app,using the native logic of blynk i.e param.asInt().hence i cannot use the logic of the normal switch like:

```
if (digitalRead(PUSH_BUTTON_1) == LOW) {
digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN_1, HIGH);

// Update Button Widget
Blynk.virtualWrite(VPIN_BUTTON_1, HIGH);}
```

as i have to use relay1State which is given as param.asInt(); to update the blynk app.Also if i use this type of code i am incurring sequential toggles in the blynk app:

```
void checkPhysicalButton()
{
if (digitalRead(PUSH_BUTTON_1) == HIGH) {
  relay1State =!relay1State;
  digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN_1, relay1State);
  Blynk.virtualWrite(VPIN_BUTTON_1, relay1State);

}

else {
    digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN_1, relay1State);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(VPIN_BUTTON_1, relay1State);

 }}
```

so hence i have to use my the pushbutton state logic to remove the sequential toggles .But i am unable to use it as a  "Press for on, release for off" switch.
it works as a Toggle switch- "press once to turn and press again to turn it off."
i want to change this logic to Press for on, release for off.Please help me.Thank you!

```
BLYNK_WRITE(VPIN_BUTTON_1) {
 relay1State = param.asInt();
 digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN_1, relay1State);
}

 void checkPhysicalButton()    
{
 if (digitalRead(PUSH_BUTTON_1) == LOW) {
    // pushButton1State is used to avoid sequential toggles
  if (pushButton1State != LOW) {

  // Toggle Relay state
  relay1State = !relay1State;
  digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN_1, relay1State);

  // Update Button Widget
  Blynk.virtualWrite(VPIN_BUTTON_1, relay1State);
    }
  pushButton1State = LOW;
  } else {
pushButton1State = HIGH;
}
```

Comment: HI @TekTron, its always good to provide as much context as possible,it seems you are working with the Blynk framework but you do not specify  any info like OS, platform ect .. , more help here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: have updated it pls check it out.